# Text going out of the container div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

the css code:

```
    #overlay {
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        position: absolute;
        z-index:100;
        width: 100%;
        color:#fff;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

the html code:

```
    <div class="container" style="border:1px solid #000;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
             <div id="overlay">Overlay</div>
                    Here goes the brief introduction of the company which has branded it's logo religious in almost its entire brand and now the world knows about it. Here goes the brief introduction of the company which has branded it's logo religious in almost its entire brand and now the world knows about it. Here goes the brief introduction of the company which has branded it's logo religious in almost its entire brand and now the world knows about it. 
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

For some reason, i can't get the background overlay to show in the container. Check out the Demo: http://www.bootply.com/PJiifhEI8u

Comment: add `left: 0;` to your css? not sure I got what the problem is, but I saw a gap before the overlay background

Comment: Thank You.  Any idea how should i go ahead if i want to show the overlay only on the text and not the entire container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `top:0;` and `left:0;` positioning to the CSS:

```
#overlay {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    position: absolute;
    z-index:100;
    width: 100%;
    color:#fff;
    height: 100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

## [Updated Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/k2RzZ9XOkZ)

**Update based on your comment:**

One way to add the padding to the overlay would be to use [calc](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) to make the overlay 30px less than 100% and then add a 15px left margin to center it:

```
#overlay {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    position: absolute;
    z-index:100;
    width:calc(100% - 30px);
    color:#fff;
    height: 100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    margin-left:15px;
}
```

## [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/rXYGu2aolY)

Comment: Thank you. I want to see the white spaces between the border and the text and not have the background all over the container. Any idea how to proceed that? I tried to add padding but it didn't work.

Comment: Awesome. Didnt know about width:calc function!! Already marked correct answer :)